# Check list element parts for mandatory array

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string list of files with the same names but different extensions and an array of extensions.
Every file name must have every extension and I want to output all missing pairs.
Is there good LINQ for it?

```cs
var files = new List<string>() { "file2.jpg", "file1.jpg", "file1.png", "file2.bmp", "file3.png", "file1.bmp" };
var exts = new[] { ".png", ".bmp", ".jpg" };
```

The result must be like this

```
file2 missing .png
file3 missing .bmp, .jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var files = new List<string>() { "file2.jpg", "file1.jpg", "file1.png", "file2.bmp", "file3.png", "file1.bmp" };
        var exts = new[] { ".png", ".bmp", ".jpg" };

        var fileGroups = files
            .GroupBy(c => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(c), v => Path.GetExtension(v))
            .Select(x => new { File = x.Key, MissingExts = exts.Except(x) })
            .Where(x=> x.MissingExts.Any());
        
        foreach(var group in fileGroups)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{group.File} {string.Join(' ', group.MissingExts)}");
        }
```

Comment: I'd use `System.IO.Path` class to get file name and file extension `.GroupBy(c => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(c), v => Path.GetExtension(v))`
Same result, easier to read. Just my 2 cents

Comment: @GianPaolo yeah, you are right. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Serhii answer is efficient enough.
Anyway, I would advise to check for double extension if these files are not used internally only. There are couple of plug-and-play solutions for this one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).